# How to load partial variables from mat files

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, I have a structure saved into matlab file:

```
Ch=  
    H:[4-D double]
    D: [1x15 double]
    duration:6
    power: [1x1 struct]
```

the size of `H` is

```
size(H) = 1332  15   4   128

save(examplefile, 'Ch','-v7.3')
```

Next I explain what I want to do:

Because, the file is huge, at some point of my code, I would like to load partial variables from the file `examplefile`. For example, at one point I would like to load only the first  `1:1332/n` of `H` of the file `examplefile`;, the second time I would only load the next varaiables running from `1333/n:2*1333/n` an so on and so forth....

My question is how to load the partial variables from the file created?

Looking forward for suggestions and help

Comment: `'-v.37'`? Do you mean `'-v7.3'`?

Comment: yes sorry that is correct

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `matfile` command. Unfortunately it is very limited in indexing, indexing structs is not supported. `H` must be a individual variable in the mat file.

```
%save using individual variables
save(examplefile,'-struct','Ch','-v7.3')
%create matfile object:
data=matfile(examplefile)
%example indexing operation. Only that part of `H` is read.
part=data.H(1:3,1,1,1)
```

Comment: thank you very much. I want to ask does the save command you used save only H? How is it different then the way I used it..

Comment: @Henry By using `'-struct'`, the fields of the provided structure (here `Ch`) are stored as individual variables in the `.mat`-file. This means you will have `H`, `D`, `duration` and `power` stored as they would have been individual variables in the workspace. See [this](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/save-structure-fields-as-separate-variables.html) for an example. The output of `matfile` is a MAT-file object, that can be used to only read certain parts of the original m-file.